# ConstraintValidator with JSR 303 not working

Tags: validation, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

hi I have a problem while Implementing custom validation using `ConstraintValidator`.

I am implementing some bean validations using `JSR303` and `constraint validator` and upto now I have following implementation as

```
@ProductId// this is the problem
    @NotEmpty(message = "{Domain.NotEmpty.productid}")
    protected String productId;

    @Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z]+", message = "{Domain.Pattern.firstName}")
    ....
```

**@ProductId**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = ProductIdValidator.class)
public @interface ProductId {
    String message() default "{ProductId.validaton.Error}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    public abstract Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

**ProductIdValidator**

```
public class ProductIdValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ProductId, String> {

    @Autowired
    private RepositiryObject repo;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ProductId productId) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String string, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {

        Domain domain;
        try {
            domain = repo.getProductById(string);
        } catch (ProdctNotFoundException ex) {
            return true;
        }
        if (domain != null) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

**StackTrace**

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.] with root cause
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
    at java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:135)
    at com.model.domain.controller.repo.RepositiryObject.getProductById(RepositiryObject.java:45)
    at com.java.spring.custom.validation.annotations.constraints.ProductIdValidator.isValid(ProductIdValidator.java:28)
    at com.java.spring.custom.validation.annotations.constraints.ProductIdValidator.isValid(ProductIdValidator.java:1)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:448)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:617)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:580)
```

**dispatcherservlet**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator" />
<bean id="validator"
        class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
        <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource" />
    </bean>
```

......

**Edit**Since exception says that no such element is present but when I ran test its working fine as

```
 public RepositiryObject() {
            domainList = new ArrayList<>();

            Domain domain = new Domain();
            domain.setProductId("P1234");

            domainList.add(domain);

        }
@Test
    public void checkIfProductExists() {

        Assert.assertEquals("P1234", domainList.stream().filter(product -> product.getProductId().equals("P1234"))
            .map(Domain::getProductId).findAny().get());
    }
```

Now the problem is when I remove that `@ProductId` it works fine not sure what I am missing here

Comment: can you please try with @Target({ ElementType.TYPE}) only and test? and also did you get the value of productId in your validator?

Comment: Just read the stack trace of the exception: RepositiryObject.getProductById() calls get() on an empty Optional, thus causing this exception. Your problem has nothing to do with validation. The problem is that you call get() without checking first that the Optional is not empty.

Comment: @JBNizet but If I try `test` it runs successfully

Comment: Your test doesn't test your constraint validator. It also doesn't test the repository's getProductById() method that is used by the validator. And it doesn't test the case where the product does **not** exist in the database. You're just executing unrelated code in your test. A bit as if you were testing that a car works fine by riding your bicycle.